# Add crossdomain.xml to Hudson

Tags: apache-flex, security, hudson

How can I add a crossdomain.xml to the root of my Hudson server? I'm working on a Flex->Hudson bridge and I'd like to access it directly, instead of relying on a proxy to do it for me.

Thanks;

**EDIT**: This is standalone Hudson, not running on any application server.

Comment: Have you deployed Hudson to an application server, or are you running it standalone, via 'java -jar hudson.war' ?

Comment: Be very careful with those crossdomain policy files.  They can open you up to some serious security problems.  Read more in this article:
http://www.jamesward.com/2009/11/08/how-bad-crossdomain-policies-expose-protected-data-to-malicious-applications/

Comment: I'm running it standalone, through -jar. Else I would just upload the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a standard crossdomain.xml and using jar uf to add it to hudson.war. I'm not sure if this is the "best" way to do it, but it did the trick for me.

I was also using the Authorization header to add a job to Hudson, so I had to use

```
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="Authorization"/>
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new text file named crossdomain.xml.
2. Open crossdomain.xml in a text editor.
3. Add the following XML code to the file:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy 
       SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
     <cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-access-from domain="www.yoursite.com" />
       <allow-access-from domain="yoursite.com" />
     </cross-domain-policy>
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. Upload the file to the root directory of yoursite.com (so that the file can be accessed at http://www.yoursite.com/crossdomain.xml).

Comment: Hudson is running standalone, not on an application server.